# Cannot install Homebrew in Mac Sierra

Tags: ruby, macos, curl, homebrew, macos-sierra

I have a problem installing homebrew in mac sierra.

I followed the instructions from this link:
https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/installing-homebrew-on-macos-sierra-package-manager-for-unix-apps/

This is the command:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

The link exists but when I type this in the terminal, I encounter this error:
curl: (35) Server aborted the SSL handshake

Can anyone suggest a solution to this?

Many thanks, Ill appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install

Open the link in browser and save the file as install.rb.
Then run

> ruby install.rb

Comment: ooppss.. I encountered this error using this: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/': Server aborted the SSL handshake
Failed during: git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master --tags --force --depth=1

Comment: Check system time. Also 1. log in to your Github account. 2. Go to Settings -> SSH and GPG keys 3. Remove old or unused keys.

Comment: There are no keys in my account. The same problem occurs

Comment: **ssh -vvv git@github.com** Run that command in console for further debugging

Comment: I got this, the error starts here: debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/lyndz/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /Users/lyndz/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directorydebug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey)

Comment: I was able to install it already. Its the proxy thats blocking the installation..sigh!

Answer (score 1):

I run into this issue, and it is caused by the network unstabitily.

My solution is:

Uninstall the `homebrew`:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

Then install it again:

```
ruby -e "$(curl --insecure -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `xcode-select --install` before that command? This solution may work on some systems.

Another potential issue is your curl maybe too old. Upgrade to 7.46+ may solve this. You have to build curl from scratch if so.

If nothing helps, and you really want to install brew without second thought, try adding `--insecure` after `-fsSL`.

At last, you can always pull the git repo and install manually.

Comment: @halfelf.I tried your 1st suggestion but still not working. I just purchased this macbook so i think the curl is up to date. Is this the correct way of doing your fourth suggestion?[see this link](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Installation.md#installation)

Comment: @Lyndz Yes. The `Alternative Installs` section is about manual installation.

Comment: I still encounter this:
curl: (35) Server aborted the SSL handshake. Does this have to do with the github site? I type the one liner command mkdir homebrew.... from the link

Comment: I was able to install it already. Its the proxy thats blocking the installation..sigh!

Answer (score 0):

Please use this to install homebrew in MacOS, previous one was deprecated.

```sh
$ /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```